# Factoring numbers "of the (binary quadratic) form" in two different ways

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms

For some fixed $n$ define the quadratic form $$Q(x,y) = x^2 + n y^2.$$

I think that if $Q$ represents $m$ in two different ways then $m$ is composite.

I can prove this for $n$ prime. I was hoping someone could give me a hint towards proving this result for general $n$? Also would be interested in generalizations if any are known! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below is Lucas' classic proof, from his *Theorie des nombres*, 1891, as described in section 215 of Mathews: [Theory of Numbers.](http://books.google.com/books?id=iQ_vAAAAMAAJ&pg=PP1)
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

John Brillhart published a paper about this in the American Mathematical Monthly some time in the past year.

Comment: I think it's [A Note on Euler's Factoring Problem](http://www.jstor.org/pss/40391253).

Comment: Yes, that's the paper I had in mind.

Comment: I cannot access this but thank you for the comment.

Comment: @quanta, that's what libraries are for. Another approach would be to send email to Professor Brillhart. But maybe Bill's answer has given you what you need.

Comment: @quanta: Brillhart's paper also employs Lucas' proof.